# Artisan can't connect to composer in containers

Tags: laravel, docker, composer-php

I am doing laravel application and installing [Laravel jetstream](https://jetstream.laravel.com/1.x/installation.html) in Docker containers. I have separate containers for composer and artisan. And when I try to install jetstream by command:

```
docker-compose run --rm artisan jetstream:install inertia
```

I get an error:

```
Starting mysql ... done
sh: exec: line 1: composer: not found
Unable to locate publishable resources.
Publishing complete.

Inertia scaffolding installed successfully.
Please execute the "npm install && npm run dev" command to build your assets.
```

The webpage still doesn't work with error message `Class 'Inertia\Inertia' not found`. I assume there is a problem with connection between composer and artisan containers, but how I can set up this connection?

Docker-compose.yml

```
  composer:
    image: composer:latest
    container_name: composer
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    depends_on:
      - php
    networks:
      - laravel

  artisan:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: artisan
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    entrypoint: ['/var/www/html/artisan']
    networks:
      - laravel
```

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Sadly I can't comment yet (< 50 reputation), but had a similar issue as you just now, an alternative to running it in different containers is to make a helper container and executing it all inside:

`docker-compose.yml` (note: `./code` is your laravel root/folder)

```
version: '3'

services:
  helper:
    build: ./composer-artisan-helper
    volumes:
      - ./code:/app
```

Make a folder `composer-artisan-helper` and create a `Dockerfile` inside:

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm

# Install git
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y git

# Get latest Composer
COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

# Keep running
ENTRYPOINT ["tail", "-f", "/dev/null"]

# Set work-directory
WORKDIR /app
```

Now run it and drop into that container:

```
docker-compose exec helper bash
```

make sure it now has all your laravel folder by doing a quick `ls` - if everything is fine execute

```
php artisan jetstream:install inertia
```

you should now be greeted eventually with `Inertia scaffolding installed successfully.`.

Hope that helps! even though it's not split up into multiple containers (which isn't possible afaik anyway).

Comment: Thank you for post. I'm not familiar with helpers containers, but I try to avoid them, because I have already enough. And fortunately I found workaround for my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to install it with command:

```
docker-compose run --rm artisan jetstream:install inertia
```

But actually it works when I try to run it in second container:

```
docker-compose run --rm composer php artisan jetstream:install inertia
```

In my configuration artisan container doesn't have a connection to the composer, but the composer container has to the artisan obviously.

Answer (score 0):

there is a right answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64309122/14401698)! thank you [Jsowa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7082164/jsowa)

But you can install related packages separately.
You need to install **inertiajs** package for laravel with the following command.

1. docker-compose run --rm composer require inertiajs/inertia-laravel
2. docker-compose run --rm artisan inertia:middleware